# Summarizing binned feature attributes after spatial join?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-join

I am trying to perform a spatial join of cell traffic data to RF Coverage polygons. What I am trying to do is perform a spatial join between the traffic and the coverage polygons so that the total amount of traffic (join features) is equivalent to the amount of traffic that intersects the coverage polygons (target features) after the spatial join. I am using one-to-one matching and I have Keep All Target Features selected.

The traffic data is in 10m hexagon bins and the total amount of traffic adds up to 437gb. Ideally, this should also be the total amount of traffic "captured" after this process. I did a select by location for all of the traffic that intersects the coverage polygons. At the end of the process, the total amount of traffic "captured" by the coverage polygons should be exactly the same as the standalone traffic data, and no bin should be captured more than once by a respective polygon.

However, the problem is that none of the Match Options seem to perfectly capture all of the traffic. Some of the traffic is double counted because the extent of the bin sometimes falls across the boundary of two or more coverage polygons. Using the intersect option is a perfect example of this happening. Since the bin intersects more than one polygon the amount of traffic for the bin is summarized into the total for each polygon, resulting in an inflated sum. Using other match options like "Contains" or "Closest" still results in imperfect capturing of the data and either inflates the sum or does not sum up perfectly to the total of 437Gbs. Below is an example image with areas circled where bins overlap with more than one polygon and are either doubled counted during summarization or not counted at all.

[image: Example image with areas where traffic bins overlap between two coverage polygons]

Is there perhaps another method of performing this spatial join that would result in a perfect capturing of the data?

Comment: Recommend you add some images to your question. Large blocks of text attempting to describe a problem are difficult to follow.

Comment: Sorry, added a picture with areas circled that show bins that overlap between two polygons.

Comment: Try the [near tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) to capture the relationship of hexagon with polygons? Then use it to summarize your data.